# Visual Studio Code on Linux 32-bits

Tags: linux, visual-studio

Microsoft launched the Visual Studio Code versions for Linux and Mac, but the documentation is a little poor.

I downloaded the Linux version (which is a binary) and when I came to run the program, I had this error:

> -bash: ./Code: cannot execute binary file: Error in exec format

I think it's because the program is for 64-bit versions only but I can possibly be wrong. I didn't found anything in the docs so, did I miss something? Anybody already made it or know what is happening?

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The official build ships with a 64 bits version of electron, but you can install a 32 bits version on your system and use it to run visual studio code.

Install electron with:

```
npm install electron-prebuilt -g
```

Then run:

```
electron PATH_TO_VSCODE/resources/app
```

You may also need to install a version of Mono >= 3.0.12 if you want VSCode to run the OmniSharp server (this is what gives code completion, refactoring, ... for C# projects).

This solution worked for me, except that I can't find dnx commands in the command palette.

(edit: added note about mono)

Comment: You are 100% right! Thank you a lot!

Comment: Just to know, where did you find that out?

Comment: I found it out on my own.

Answer (score 0):

You can't run 64 bit programs on a 32 bit OS, so it's not going to work, unless they release a 32 bit build - which I doubt.

Comment: `unless they release a 32 bit build - which I doubt.` https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/?dv=linux32 It's there, they just don't like to it. ¬_¬